# Does the Pinterest V5 API allow access to board-level data?

Tags: rest, pinterest

Specifically, could you create a report with pin data from a specified board? I have multiple brands each with multiple boards. I'd like to track the performance metrics of pins based on their board.

I'm assuming this https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/v5/#operation/boards/list_pins is explaining how to do it, but I wasn't quite sure.